# Pagoda Box image upload problems

Tags: php, image, upload

I am working on a site as an experiment to teach myself php, I have had most of it completed now for a while and working fine. I recently switched hosting from dreamhost to pagoda box and ran into some obvious problems.

I have another site on pagoda that uses the kohana  framwork and is set up to use a mongo database, but in order for kohana and mongo to work properly the cache and log directories have to be writable and the extensions are needed. Which is when I found out about the Boxfile, I added the Boxfile with the directories and the problems were solved.

However after trying to upload a new image to the site I switched from dreamhost I got the php error saying the dir was read only, so I added a Boxfile to that site with the images dir, but it broke all of my images on the site with exception to the ones that I used the cms to upload. In other words all of the images that were previously on there were broken and the ones that I recently uploaded worked, but before the Boxfile it was reverse.

Sorry if that is a little confusing, it is a weird problem and I can't find much help on it other than Pagoda Box's guide to the basics on their Boxfile. I can elaborate if needed.

This is what I have on the boxfile now:

web1: #component type & number
  shared_writable_dirs:
    - images

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you specify a directory as a shared writable dir on Pagoda Box, they use network mounts to connect all of your web instances to to a single writable filesystem. These mounts essentially hide any files contained in those directories inside your repo. When your app tries to grab something in those directory, the mount routes the request into the shared filesystem (which currently doesn't have your images in it).

Under the Admin tab in your dashboard, [enable SSH access to your shared writable storage](http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/articles/175469-enabling-ssh-access-to-app-logs-and-shared-storage) and upload all of the files into the proper shared directories. Once they're uploaded, your app will be able to find them.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. I thought something like that might be the case but I guess I wanted to hear it from someone else first.